# TImeseries chart get replicated in all the parts of GUI in eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse, jfreechart, e4

I am using JFreechart in eclipse e4 application. I have dynamically created parts in a partstack say A. Each parts show some graph based on the selections other partstack say B. If I am in first part and made some selections from partstack B, the graph should be updated according to the selections I made. If I click on the second part and select some other inputs , it should show new gragh only in the second part.

My problem is when I click on the second part and select some inputs and the graph is drawn but the changes in the graph are also replicated in the first part.

For sending the data from partstack B to parts in the partstack A, I am using the Eventbroker service.

```
   @Inject
   @Optional
   void getStatisticEvent(@UIEventTopic("values_stat/UI_Event")ArrayList<TreeMap<Timestamp, Long>> statisticalValues){
   //some code to create the timeseries 
   dataset.addSeries(t);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Eventbroker service broadcasts events to everyone interested in particular event. That's why every part creates the timeseries and adds it to dataset. In your `getStatisticEvent` method you must check that this part is the current one. `MPartStack.getSelectedElement()` should help.